# Programmatically Get Page Layout being used by a SharePoint Page

Tags: development, pages

Wondered if it's possible to iterate through the pages held in the pages library and determine the page layout being used by each page? any c# code examples appreciated.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to use [`PublishingPage.GetPublishingPage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.publishingpage.getpublishingpage.aspx) to get the page, then use that to get Layout.

For example:

```
var pagesList = web.Lists["Pages"];
pagesList.GetItems(new SPQuery()).Cast<SPListItem>().ToList().ForEach(item => {
  if (!PublishingPage.IsPublishingPage(item)) return;

  var publishingPage = PublishingPage.GetPublishingPage(item);
  Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Page '{0}' use layout named '{1}' with title '{2}'", 
     publishingPage.Title,
     publishingPage.Layout.Name, 
     publishingPage.Layout.Title));
});
```

Comment: I'm trying something similar to test this but keep getting a "Value does not fall within expected range error" says the SPListItem is not compatible with a PublishingPage:



    `SPList MyPages = web.Lists["Pages"];
    SPListItemCollection MyPagesColl =  MyPages.GetItems(Customview);

    foreach(int i=0; i<MyPagesColl.Count;i++)
    {
        SPListItem item = MyPagesColl[i];

    //error occurs here   
    PublishingPage Page = PublishingPage.GetPublishingPage(item);
    
    TestLabel.Text = Page.Layout.Name;
    }`

Comment: That `foreach` looks very suspicious, have you tried `foreach (var item in myPagesColl){...}`? And what does `PublishingPage.IsPublishingPage(item))` give you?

Answer (score 1):

Use SPSiteDataQuery to get all the pages or filter them w.r.t their associated Content Types. See example below

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb;
SPSiteDataQuery query = new SPSiteDataQuery();

//Server template for pages library is 850
query.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate='850' Hidden='TRUE' />";  

query.ViewFields = @"<FieldRef Name='URL' Nullable='True' Type='URL' /><FieldRef Name='Title' Nullable='TRUE' Type='Text' />";

query.Webs = "<Webs Scope='Recursive'  />";
query.Query = @"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ContentType'/><Value Type='Text'>CT_Page_News</Value></Eq></Where>"
DataTable dt = web.GetSiteData(query);
```

> SPSiteDataQuery: this class used for cross site query. Query a data
>   within site collection or specific web.