# How to customize color of words in ribbon in Sharepoint (2013)?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, theme

How do I customize the colors for the words 
"BROWSE" and "PAGE" only? These words are in the ribbon at the top left corner of the SharePoint site.

[image]

I tried using the method of editing a Palette(number).spcolor file in SharePoint Designer 2013, which can be found under the path "../../_catalogs/theme/15", but I realized that editing the words "BROWSE" and "PAGE" from there, will cause all the fonts in my entire site to be affected. I only need those 2 words to have a different color.

Comment: You can use this as a refference:<br>
[Exemple Topic](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/199524/how-to-change-the-tab-name-in-sharepoint)

Comment: Use browser F12 developer tools to get the correct selector id or class. Then use CSS to give color to the selector. Heather Solomon made a list with most SP CSS selectors: [link](https://blog.sharepointexperience.com/css-charts/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following CSS code to change it:

```
<style>
#Ribbon\.Read-title > .ms-cui-tt-a > .ms-cui-tt-span {
    color: red!important;
}

#Ribbon\.WikiPageTab-title >.ms-cui-tt-a > .ms-cui-tt-span {
    color: red!important;
}
</style>
```

If you want to change that on the entire site, you can add the code into the master page of the site.